# I don't know which of AI branch is will solve my problem

Tags: database, android-studio, artificial-intelligence

What should I use, machine learning, text analysis or pattern recognition if I have a set of words and I want to find a pattern between them and then look for this pattern in a long text?

Comment: This is a really vague question. It completely depends on what patterns you are looking for and what type of text. Could you define the problem more specifically? Perhaps, give some examples of what you mean, I think it will help greatly in getting an answer.

Comment: thanks for replay.. The idea is some English words have the same letters in them, like aim, aid, bail, bait ... etc and I’m not sure what to use to find the pattern between them which are the letters ai. 
After that whenever I would enter a text ( for example a book) it would find all the words that have (ai) in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build the n-grams of all the words.

```
from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter

words = ["aim", "aid", "bail", "bait"]


def build_ngrams(words, from_size, to_size):
    word_ngrams = []

    for word in words:
        for ngram_size in range(from_size, to_size + 1):
            ng = ngrams(word, ngram_size)
            word_ngrams.extend(ng)

    return word_ngrams


# construct all bigrams and trigrams
word_ngrams = build_ngrams(words, 2, 3)

# find the most common n-grams
counter = Counter(word_ngrams)
print(counter.most_common(3))
```

This will give you the most common patterns, and you can use that later for your search.

Comment: Ok thanks !! I will try it.
by the way, this is my first time to deal with python language, so maybe I will take some time to test the code.
and thanks again for your answer.

the last question, if I want to do something like this code in an android studio, can be or not?

Comment: Yea definitely writing your own ngram function is really easy. You just iterate over a sequence creating all the tuples of size N you want. Then you have all the tuples in a list and can frequency count them to get the most common.

Comment: now I got it !! thanks a lot !!